# Rename default admin role in ABP framework

Tags: permissions, roles, abp

Is there a way to rename the default `admin` role to something else, e.g. `system admin` or `super admin` ? In some contexts , `admin` may refer to task administrator or maybe other administrator and I'd use that for something else.

Yes, I can delete all permission granted to `admin` and grant them to `system admin`, however I'm not sure other places where the default `admin` are used in.
And since [data seeder](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/permission-management/src/Volo.Abp.PermissionManagement.Domain/Volo/Abp/PermissionManagement/PermissionDataSeedContributor.cs) is hardcoded to `admin`, I'm kinda stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I handled it:

```cs
public static class IdentityDataSeederProperties
{
    public static String AdminUserName { get; set; } = "admin";
    public static String AdminRoleName { get; set; } = "admin";
}

[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]
public class IdentityDataSeeder : ITransientDependency, IIdentityDataSeeder
{
    protected IGuidGenerator GuidGenerator { get; }
    protected IIdentityRoleRepository RoleRepository { get; }
    protected IIdentityUserRepository UserRepository { get; }
    protected ILookupNormalizer LookupNormalizer { get; }
    protected IdentityUserManager UserManager { get; }
    protected IdentityRoleManager RoleManager { get; }
    protected ICurrentTenant CurrentTenant { get; }
    protected IOptions<IdentityOptions> IdentityOptions { get; }
    protected ILogger<IdentityDataSeeder> Logger { get; }

    public IdentityDataSeeder(
        IGuidGenerator guidGenerator,
        IIdentityRoleRepository roleRepository,
        IIdentityUserRepository userRepository,
        ILookupNormalizer lookupNormalizer,
        IdentityUserManager userManager,
        IdentityRoleManager roleManager,
        ICurrentTenant currentTenant,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
        ILogger<IdentityDataSeeder> logger)
    {
        GuidGenerator = guidGenerator;
        RoleRepository = roleRepository;
        UserRepository = userRepository;
        LookupNormalizer = lookupNormalizer;
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        CurrentTenant = currentTenant;
        IdentityOptions = identityOptions;
        Logger = logger;
    }

    public virtual async Task<IdentityDataSeedResult> SeedAsync(String adminEmail, String adminPassword, Guid? tenantId = null)
    {
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminEmail, nameof(adminEmail));
        Check.NotNullOrWhiteSpace(adminPassword, nameof(adminPassword));

        using (CurrentTenant.Change(tenantId))
        {
            await IdentityOptions.SetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            var result = await CreateAdminUserAndRoleAsync(adminEmail, adminPassword, tenantId).ConfigureAwait(false);

            await AddAdminUserToAdminRole().ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result;
        }
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    private async Task AddAdminUserToAdminRole()
    {
        var adminUser = await UserRepository
            .FindByNormalizedUserNameAsync(LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminUserName))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        (await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminRoleName).ConfigureAwait(false)).CheckErrors();
    }

    [UnitOfWork]
    private async Task<IdentityDataSeedResult> CreateAdminUserAndRoleAsync(String adminEmail, String adminPassword, Guid? tenantId)
    {
        return new IdentityDataSeedResult
        {
            CreatedAdminUser = await CreateAdminUserIfItDoesNotExistAsync(tenantId, adminEmail, adminPassword).ConfigureAwait(false),
            CreatedAdminRole = await CreateAdminRoleIfItDoesNotExistAsync(tenantId).ConfigureAwait(false)
        };
    }

    private async Task<Boolean> CreateAdminRoleIfItDoesNotExistAsync(Guid? tenantId)
    {
        var adminRole = await RoleRepository
            .FindByNormalizedNameAsync(LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminRoleName))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (adminRole == null)
        {
            adminRole = new IdentityRole(GuidGenerator.Create(), IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminRoleName, tenantId)
            {
                IsStatic = true,
                IsPublic = true
            };

            (await RoleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole).ConfigureAwait(false)).CheckErrors();

            Logger.LogInformation("Created Role: {RoleName} ({RoleId})", adminRole.Name, adminRole.Id);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private async Task<Boolean> CreateAdminUserIfItDoesNotExistAsync(Guid? tenantId, String adminEmail, String adminPassword)
    {
        var adminUser = await UserRepository.FindByNormalizedUserNameAsync(
            LookupNormalizer.NormalizeName(IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminUserName)
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (adminUser == null)
        {
            adminUser = new IdentityUser(GuidGenerator.Create(), IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminUserName, adminEmail, tenantId)
            {
                Name = IdentityDataSeederProperties.AdminUserName
            };

            (await UserManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, adminPassword, validatePassword: false).ConfigureAwait(false)).CheckErrors();

            Logger.LogInformation("Created User: {RoleName} ({RoleId})", adminUser.Name, adminUser.Id);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The key is the `[Dependency(ReplaceServices = true)]` attribute. It causes the DI system to replace the default implementation with mine.

NOTE: I refactored the default implementation (and added logging) which is why I didn't just inherit from it, as suggested in [#9641](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/9641).